# Where is signed-aligned apk output? (Maven)

Tags: output, apk, release, android-maven-plugin

Where does the signed and aligned apk go when I do Maven release?

The only place I can find a "app-signed-aligned.apk" is in ./trunk/target/checkout/projectname/target/app-signed-aligned.apk

Is this the apk that I should use to send to Play? Or where is it? In .m2 folder? Checkout dir seems a strange place to put the output in...

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the Maven lifecycle phase you run

- package: find it in target
- install: find it in .m2/...
- deploy: find it in the repository in your Maven repository manager (like Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager)